# Solr - Search parent having multiple child documents

Tags: solr, parent-child, nested-documents, solr-search, solr.net

I have a Solr index with structure as below.

```
{
"id": "1",
"bookName_s": "Core Concepts",
"bookDescription_s": "This is the description",
"isbn_s": "ABCD:123",    
"reviews": [
  {
    "id": "2",
    "Name_s": "review1",
    "detail_s": "sample review"
  }
],
"students": [
  {
    "id": "3",
    "Name_s": "student1",
    "student_s": "test student"
  }
]
```

}

How do i search for parent that has a reviewer with Name_s as 'review1' and student with Name_s as 'student'.

I tried parent block chain query like below but nothing seems to work -

```
q=({!parent which="*:* -_nest_path_:*"}(+_nest_path_:\/reviews +Name_s:*rev*)) AND ({!parent which="*:* -_nest_path_:*"}(+_nest_path_:\/students +Name_s:*stu*)) 

q=({!parent which="*:* -_nest_path_:*"}(+_nest_path_:\/reviews +Name_s:*rev*)(+_nest_path_:\/students +Name_s:*stu*))
```

Is there a way i can acheive this using the q operator instead of fq parameter? thanks

Comment: Yes but you need to properly specifiy _which_ parent, here you pass `*:* -<filter>`, but you have better to add a specific field to help distinguish parent-child relationships even if you don't have a recursive structure, eg. using a string field `type` filled accordingly with 'book', 'review' or 'student', and then use a query like `q={!parent which="type:book"}<children>` where <children> is your children filter : `(type:review AND Name_s:review1) OR (type:student AND Name_s:student1)`.

Comment: Hi @EricLavault thanks for your reply. I noticed this statement in the solr documentations. 

`// BAD! DO NOT USE!
q={!parent which="title:join"}comments:support`

[link](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/other-parsers.html#block-mask)

It says that it would return documents that do no match the filter. Is there a way to get the query working with the nest path?

Comment: My proposition has nothing to do with the filter `title:join`, which is bad because a title is (usually) free text and both some of the parents and children documents may contain the term 'join' in their title, so you can't really distinguish them. Now if you read correctly, I precisely suggest to prevent that by using a field whose values are constrained and allows to properly discern which documents are the parents, ie. `type:book`.

Comment: @EricLavault thanks for the reply. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on EricLavault suggestion i modified the index to include type of the object in the index like below -

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "bookName_s": "Core Concepts",
    "bookDescription_s": "This is the description",
    "isbn_s": "ABCD:123",
    "type_s":"book"    
    "reviews": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "Name_s": "review1",
        "detail_s": "sample review",
        "type":"review"
      }
    ],
    "students": [
      {
        "id": "3",
        "Name_s": "student1",
        "type":"student",
        "student_s": "test student"
      }
    ]
    }
```

and below queries worked.

```
{!parent which="type:book"}(type:review AND Name_s:review1) OR (type:student AND Name_s:student1)
```

returns all books with review1 and student1

Comment: I thought we had to use the _childDocuments_ attribute when making nested documents. How would you retain the field names (reviews, students)